# not able to require publish module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

Im was publish module to npm (very simple module for testing purpose)  and it seems that I was not able to require it.

when I do npm install --save I saw that the package is located inside the node_modules (and new entry was created in the package.json) folder and in my server.js file I do

```
var myModule = require('nodewrapapp');
```

and I got the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'nodewrapapp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

The module contain only one very simple file :

```
function startInterval(fn) {
    fn(); // do the function right now
    return setInterval.apply(this, arguments); // defer to setInterval
}

module.exports = startInterval; // let me be required
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main to server.js

```
{
  "name": "nodewrapapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "server.js", // Here
  ...
}
```

Comment: Im not able to require it...do you? how?

Comment: found it ! change in your package.json the main parameter to server.js